# Best approach to maintain a class

Tags: java, software-design

Lets say I had a class DFS that took Graph as constructor argument and source as doDfs parameter.

```
public class DFS {
    final Graph g;
    list path;

    public DFS(Graph g) {
      this.g = g;
    }

    public void doDfs(int source) {
      // dfs computation
      populate path.

    }
 }
```

Now in future I need to extend this class and add another function 'printPathToSource'.

```
public class DFS {
    final Graph g;
    list path;

    public DFS(Graph g) {
      this.g = g;
    }

    public void doDfs(int source) {
      // dfs computation
      populate path.

    }

    public void printPathToSource(int vertex) {
        // dfs computation
        populate path.

      }
 }
```

Now a few options open up,

### 1. Store source as an instance variable but dont pass it in cosntructor.

```
public class DFS {
    final Graph g;
    list path;
    int source; // <------ NOTE the new field.

    public DFS(Graph g) {
      this.g = g;
    }

    public void doDfs(int source) {
      // dfs computation
      populate path.
      if (souce == null) {
         this.source = source;
      }
    }

    public void printPathToSource(int vertex) {
        // dfs computation
        populate path using this.source
      }
 }
```

### Disadvantage:

```
DFS dfs = new DFS(graph);
// some code
dfs.doDfs(5);
// some code
dfs.doDfs(7);  
// some code
dfs.printPath(10); // <-- cannot direct this function if it wants the output of 5 or 7.
```

### 2. Specify source again & dont store it as instance variable:

```
dfs.printPath(10,  source == 5)
Disadvantage: Redundant parameter passing,
```

### 3. Add another constructor.

```
public class DFS {
    final Graph g;
    list path;
    int source; // <------ NOTE the new field.

    public DFS(Graph g) {
      this.g = g;
    }

    public DFS(Graph g, int source) {
        this.g = g;
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void doDfs() {
        doDfs(this.source);
    }

    public void doDfs(source) {
      // dfs computation
      populate path.
    }

    public void printPathToSource(int vertex) {
        // dfs computation
        populate path using this.source
      }
 }
```

### Disadvantage:

Introducing an additional instance variable. For a new source a new object would be created. This means for a new source create a new object.
The value of field source is very different in each call and its uneccessary to make it instance variable.

Please suggest me a good approach for code maintainance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Overload `printPathToSource()`?

```
public void printPathToSource(int vertex) {
    this.printPathToSource(this.source, vertex);
}

public void printPathToSource(int source, int vertex) {
    // PROFIT!
}
```

Comment: Yes, but still which of the above approaches would you use for getting the value of this.source ??

Comment: It is up to you to define what the class represents... it makes sense to define a permanent source? If not, leave it out of the class and use it always as a parameter. If it is required, require it in the constructor. If it is useful but not required, use a setter.

Comment: That said, the only reason I could see to define a `source` beforehand (not as a method parameter) would be if you use it to do some previous optimizations so the others methods run faster. And I would doub before doing it that way, if not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class `DFS` is responsible for storing a Graph and doing some calculation on this Graph, which is independent of 'source' (see your example 1 for doDFS(source) )

But the class is not responsible for storing the final results. So, what I suggest from my experience, is: try to decouple your Classes, think abiut the responsibilities of each class.

Ultimately, I would have a Class `DFSResult`, which contains the results DFS calculated (if a List / Map does not suffice) and a Class `DFSResultWriter`, which can take a `DFSResult` and a `source` and populate the result. `DFS` should not know about sources, but only how to store it's results in a `DFSResult` instance.

Later on, there might come the point that you want to write to different sources. So better put the methods of `DFSResultWriter` in an interface and create different implementations for each source type, you have. Maybe even `Source` might become an interface, and you have different implementations of `Source`.

So `Source` could have an instance method:

`source.writeDFSResult(DFSResult dfsResult)`